# Pending Developer Release and Promo Codes (cancelling a release)

Tags: ios

We currently have a 1.0 app at status of Pending Developer Release and have a number of users using it via promo codes. Based on feedback we've had to create an updated version and need to push that up for review. To do this we'll have to cancel the version that's there and start the review process again.

The question is though, what happens to the users who have installed 1.0 via promo codes. Will this version still be available to them until their 4 week period expires or does the app get removed automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app will remain on their devices, but will no longer be available to download if you cancel the release.